# WebView not loading my web site

Tags: android, webview

I have my Android App that does a POST on my WEB API `http://<myip>:6262/api/values`. Then gets from the response body a string like this `http://<myip>:8082/Folder/index.htlm`. Then I load my `WebView` with the response of the WEB API.

I can access my server everywhere, ports are open (both 6262 and 8082 for UDP and TCP, and firewall does allow in and outbound connections for them)

I'm in a AsyncTask:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
 mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               mWebView.loadUrl("http://<myip>:8082/Folder/index.htlm");
            }
        });
}
```

Nothing loads, I got a blank view. Even if I `loadUrl` in `OnCreate()`.
But if I use `http://google.com` it works...
I tried to load `http://<myip>:8082/Folder/index.htlm` inside chrome in the phone and it worked. Any idea why it won't load inside the app?

Comment: put your mWebView code

Comment: Try to put in it in `onPostExecute`

Comment: without your code we can't help you. we can only guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test1);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }
    });
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
}
```

Comment: Thank you enabling Javascript was the solution.